# My application is throwing cursor index outOfBounds exception,requested -1 with size of 1

Tags: android, cursor, blob

When I try to retrieve a blob from my sqlite database, the cursor is throwing an `index outofbounds` exception.

My DataBaseHelper class is:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String Database_Name="images.db";
    public static final String Table_Name="imgs";
    Bitmap bitmap;
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Database_Name,null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+Table_Name+"(id integer primary key autoincrement , image blob)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if esists "+Table_Name);
    }
    public boolean insert(byte[] img)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("image",img);
        long insert=db.insert(Table_Name,null,cv);
        if(insert==-1)
        {
            return  false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And my Results class:

```
public class Results extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    DataBaseHelper mDataBaseHelper;
    Bitmap img;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        mDataBaseHelper=new DataBaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db=mDataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Emm",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select* from "+mDataBaseHelper.Table_Name,null);
        byte[] imageArray=cursor.getBlob(3);
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray,0,imageArray.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

The above results code is throwing `cursor index outofbounds exception,index -1 requested with size of 1`.

Answer (score 1):

`if (cursor.moveToNext()){
cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(yourColumnName));
}`

In this way you move the cursor on the first row of your returned data set.
In any way a space seems to miss in your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

The table `mDataBaseHelper.Table_Name` from which you want to fetch the rows, 
by executing this statement:

```
"select * from " + mDataBaseHelper.Table_Name
```

has only 1 column, but you try to get the 4th by:

```
byte[] imageArray=cursor.getBlob(3);
```

The `CREATE` statement in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class shows that there are 2 columns in the table: `id` and `image`, so you should do:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    byte[] imageArray=cursor.getBlob(1);
}
cursor.close();
```

try it, but if you get the same error again, this means that the table existing in the db has only 1 column.  
So if the problem persists uninstall the app from the emulator/device so the db will be deleted and run again to recreate the table. Then repopulate the table.

Comment: If you tried `getBlob(1)` and you got `indexoutofbounds` error, then your table has only 1 column!